# PHP Multiple Checkbox Array Not Sending All Values

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox

I read over some questions on Stackoverflow but none of them solved my issue, but maybe I just overlooked something because I lack proficiency in PHP.

I know the form code is correct, but there is something wrong in my PHP because only the last element of the checkboxes gets sent upon completion of the form.

I'm not asking for a solution, I just need a kick in the right direction so I know what I am doing wrong.

Sorry, I am not familiar with back end so this is a learning process for me.

Thanks!

Here is the PHP (changed email for privacy):

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $company = $_POST['company'];
        $website = $_POST['website'];
        $checkboxes = $_POST['checkboxvar'];
           foreach ($checkboxes as $checkboxes=>$value) {
                     $value."\n";
                }
        $timeframe = $_POST['timeframe'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $to = 'example@example.com'; 
        $subject = 'Full Contact Form';

        $body ="Name: $name\n\n
        E-Mail: $email\n\n 
        Phone: $phone\n\n 
        Company: $company\n\n 
        Website: $website\n\n 
        Checkboxes: $value\n
        Time Frame: $timeframe\n\n 
        Project Description:\n\n $description";

        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        if (!$_POST['description']) {
            $errDescription = 'Please enter your project description';
        }

if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errDescription) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success alert-success-full-contact">Your request has been sent!</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger alert-danger-full-contact">Sorry, there was an error. Try again later!</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is this - `foreach ($checkboxes as $checkboxes=>$value) { $value."\n"; }` What ae you trying to do here?

Comment: You should post your form as well. And note that only marked checkboxes get sent to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your problem and the code, your form could very well be correct but as you mentioned, you are only sending the last value:

```
foreach ($checkboxes as $checkboxes=>$value) {
   $value."\n";
}
...
Checkboxes: $value\n
```

Note that `$value` contains the last value of the loop, so the value of the last checked box.

Instead of that loop, you probably want something like:

```
$value = implode(', ', $_POST['checkboxvar']);
```

This will get you a comma separated list of the values of the checked checkboxes.

Or if you want new-lines like in your example:

```
$value = implode("\n", $_POST['checkboxvar']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the way you're looping through the checkbox values.

```
foreach ($checkboxes as $checkboxes=>$value) {
  $value."\n";
}
```

Right now, you're constantly overwriting `$value`' s value

Instead, use something like

```
$selectedValues = "";
foreach ($checkboxes as $checkboxes=>$value) {
  $selectedValues .= $value ."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this?:

```
foreach ($checkboxes as $checkboxes=>$value) {
                     $value."\n";
                }
```

If you are trying to see checkboxes values you have to put:

```
echo $value."\n";
```

It doesn't have sense